# Mouse Locking After MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN SendInput

Tags: c, winapi

I have been trying to toggle down and up the mouse to simulated dragging a window. The problem i have been noticing is that  when i call toggle down for too long (say maybe 200 milliseconds), it locks the mouse and doesn't process any other mouse events until i manually unlock the mouse. Is there something i can call in the code provided to prevent this?

```c
    INPUT mouseInput;
    mouseInput.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    mouseInput.mi.dx = 0;
    mouseInput.mi.dy = 0;
    mouseInput.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
    mouseInput.mi.time = 0; //System will provide the timestamp
    mouseInput.mi.dwExtraInfo = 0;
    mouseInput.mi.mouseData = 0;
    SendInput(1, &mouseInput, sizeof(mouseInput));
```

Comment: Where is the **MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP** event ?

Comment: What mouse events do you expect it to process with the mouse button down without being released?

Comment: "*... until i manually unlock the mouse*" - and how are you doing that?